# Undexplained Array changes

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a method that creates an array by trial and error, then evaluates it to finally output the "best" array. When I read the array contents from the copied array at the if (rating < bestRating) query via System.out.println(), I get the increasingly "better" arrays. But when I then read out the arrays after the while loop, the second dimension is empty. Why does the array content change away from the query?

This are the arrays:

```
private double[][] ration //ration[0].length is always 2
```

This is how the method starts:

```
    private void suggestRation() {
        // time counter
        Stopwatch suggestionWatch = new Stopwatch();
        suggestionWatch.startO();

        // get rating reference
        int mode = loadUserRation();
        double[][] bestRation = ration.clone();
        double bestRating = submit();

        // max component items
        int max = MainClass.getRation().getComponentList().getSize();
        int lines = MainClass.getRation().getRationGrid().length(true);
        if (max > lines) {
            max = lines;
        }

        int loops = 0;
        long lapseEnd = System.nanoTime() + (long) (duration * 1.0E9);
        long lapseMin = System.nanoTime() + (long) (duration * 1.0E8);
```

Here the method works different than expected:

```
        while (System.nanoTime() < lapseEnd) {

            switch (mode) {
            case NEW:
                int components = (new Random()).nextInt(max);
                generateNewRation(components);
                break;

            case REFINE:
                generateNewAmounts();
                break;
            case EXTEND:
                expandRation();
                break;
            }

            double rating = submit();

            if (rating < bestRating) {
                bestRation = ration.clone();
                bestRating = rating;
                
                //Array is transferred correctly. 
                for (int i = 0; i < bestRation.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(bestRation[i][0] + " " +bestRation[i][1]);
                }
            }
            loops++;

            if (bestRating < 5 && System.nanoTime() > lapseMin) {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        //Second column is 0 - independent of the last output of the above if-query
        for (int i = 0; i < bestRation.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(bestRation[i][0] + " " + bestRation[i][1]);
        }

        ration = bestRation.clone();
```

My testing - array.length() == 1.
First for-query: (Every line is an array.

```
0.0 37.0
0.0 51.0
0.0 50.0
0.0 44.0
0.0 45.0
```

Second for-query:

```
0.0 0.0
```

Here should have been:

```
0.0 45.0
```

In this case the switch-case fires:

```
    private void generateNewAmounts() {

        double max_amount = Constants.FM_MAX;

        for (int i = 0; i < ration.length; i++) {
            if (ration[i][0] != -1) {
                ration[i][1] = (new Random().nextInt((int) (max_amount - 1)) + 1);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide a complete exeample that demonstrates your problem. The code you posted contains references to a lot of methods you didn't include and are therefor unknown to us and I don't even see any code that fills or prints any Array. So the code really doesn't do much to illustrate and clarify what problem it is you are exaclty having.

Comment: Hello, please provice a [mcve].

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page--it's not at all clear how anybody could help with the information provided.

Comment: Please excuse me, I am revising my question. Thanks for the suggestions on this.

Comment: It's still not at all clear what's going on. One thing to be cautious of is what you get with an array `clone`, though; it is a shallow copy.

Comment: There was a connection between the local array bestRation and the class array ration. A change of the class array resulted in the change of the local array. I have solved it now by recreating the class array each pass.